# How to open anchor tag links in external browser instead of open in same webview in xamarin.forms

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have one webview where some html content are display with some javascript and jquery and CSS. In this html content I have some **anchor tag (...) with target="_blank"** attribute. when I click on these links its open in same webview page but instead of doing this I want to open it into external browser. How is this possible in xamarin forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catch `Navigating Event` on your webview  and call `Device.Open(your uri)`

```
 webview.Navigating += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Url.StartsWith("http"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var uri = new Uri(e.Url);
                        Device.OpenUri(uri);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                    }

                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            };
```